# Firebase Error: You must enable this service in the console

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am getting the following error when trying to create a user

**Note:**  This post might seem long but in general i think its mostly installation instruction of firebase in console..

> This operation is not allowed. You must enable this service in the
>   console.

I am trying this on iPhone X device probably running latest ios in simulator.

I am using react-native-firebase module

This is how my signup action looks like

```
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";

export const signup = (fullName, username, email, password) => {
  console.log(`Full name: ${fullName} UserName: ${username} email: ${email} password: ${password}`)
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch({ type: PROFILE_LOADING });
    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(user => {
        console.log("This is user from signup", signup);
        return dispatch({
          type: PROFILE_SUCCESS,
          payload: user
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
        return dispatch({
          type: PROFILE_ERROR,
          payload: error.data
        });
      });
  };
};
```

In my firebase authentication, I have enabled signup with email and password

[image]

I have made the changes as mentioned in the docs i.e in my `AppDelegate.m`

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <Firebase.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];
   // more code
```

My pod file looks like this

```
# Pods for entreClientwithoutExpo
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'

  target 'entreClientwithoutExpo-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

    pod 'RNReanimated', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-reanimated'

  end
```

And my folder structure containing `GoogleService-Info.plist` looks like this

[image]

One thing which I did out of the instruction was to create `rn-cli.config.js`

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');

module.exports = {
  resolver:{
    blacklistRE: blacklist([
      /nodejs-assets\/.*/,
      /android\/.*/,
      /ios\/.*/
    ])
  },
};
```

**Question:** Any Idea what could I be doing wrong?

**Update:** With Web based login, it works without error but I intend to use firebase firestore and for that I need it to work natively with app

**Update:** There could be an error with bundle identifer as well?

When view the `-tvOS` bundle identifier, it happens to be is this 
    org.reactjs.native.example.entreClientwithoutExpo-tvOS

but normally it is

```
app.entre
```

Here are additional (probably releavent  screenshot

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Update 2:** My app isn't being verified as well

[image]

Also, do we need to add any URL's for the app?

Comment: have you added `google-services.json` file in your project?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you're trying to run this on a simulator, firebase doesn't allow you to login on a simulator(I have had a similar problem on android emulator).

Comment: @Heisenberg Nope. What is that file? how can we get one? how do we use it?

Comment: @anurag145 Noted but I think I might be missing/doing something wrong. Heisenberg might have figured it out

Comment: @anurag145 With web configuration it works fine. Can you confirm for sure?

Comment: @Heisenberg Sorry, I deleted the post because I thought it started working. Can you tell little more about google-service.json?

Answer (score 3):

you can skip the verification step above, but you need to have the following configuration under:

[image]

You need to correctly configure `app id` and `bundle id`.

[image]

[As explained in my post on github](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin/issues/613#issuecomment-474760487) firebase creates three api keys in your google cloud console.

One api key for your `ios` app, one for your `android` app (you don't have this one) and one api key for the `web`.

[image]

[image]

I will keep updating this posts in the future, here are some links I have been checking for your issue

https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/guides

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=medium+react+native+firebase+configuring+ios&t=canonical&ia=web

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=medium+react+native+firebase+configuring+ios&t=canonical&ia=web

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html

[Firebase Authentication error in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45967649/firebase-authentication-error-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have not included the `google-services.json` file in you project. Go to settings on firebase and download it then add to project.

[To download a config file for an Android app:](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en)

- Sign in to Firebase, then open your project.
- Click , then select Project settings.
- In the Your apps card, select the package name of the app for which you need a config file.
- Click google-services.json, then add it to your app.

Comment: Okay, I am trying this in iOS and for iOS we get `GoogleService-Info.plist`, `google-services.json` is for Android which I am not trying on at the moment

Comment: Yeah, I am pasting `GoogleService-Info.plist` (check my post) but I am still getting the same error. 

With Web based login, it works without error but I intend to use `firebase firestore` and for that I need it to work natively with app

Comment: Have you made sure to pod install after adding teh pods?, then use the white project

Comment: Yeah! I have tried pod install and pod update as well

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not as described in the documentations... but this worked for me! 
I see you added `GoogleService-Info.plist` in project folder, however I imported it  under ios folder. Simply add it into 'ios' folder and you may connect to the console. :-)
of course you'll need to clean and run your project again.

Answer (score -2):

You just need to enable the google sighin methods from console for more reference check below screenshot.

[image]

[image]